# Error during File conversion

Tags: python, database

Conversion of a multi-entry sdf to a multi-entry pdb file with open babel results in the loss of the compound names in the resulting PDB file. Why do you think this might occur and how can I resolve this issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Add more information so people can help you better. Are you using the GUI or the command line version of ob? If GUI, what are your steps, and if CLI, what are your commands?

Comment: @RamRS I am using OB GUI. I opted for sdf as the input format for file conversion and pdb as the output file format for the conversion.

Comment: http://www.cheminfo.org/Chemistry/Cheminformatics/FormatConverter/index.html just to be sure people can try it

Comment: ouch multi molecules doesnt work online